# Gathering groups (only) in regex

Tags: regular-expression

I've come across regex substitutions in vim, but was wondering if there was more the concept of something like `regex.group()` in vim. For example, from the site "VimGolf", here is one example input:

```
john doe <john.doe@mail.com>; alice hoover <alice.hoover@mail.com>; justin teen <jteen@mail.com>;
```

The goal here is to capture the emails only. Normally I would do this with something like:

```
>>> re.findall(r'<(.+?)>',s)
# ['john.doe@mail.com', 'alice.hoover@mail.com', 'jteen@mail.com']
```

Yet I haven't come across the idea of only gathering items matched by a regex as opposed to doing a substitution. Is something like that possible to do in vim, or what?

The regex I'd use for substitution here would be:

```
:s/[^<]\+<\([^>]\+\)>;/\1 /g
" john.doe@mail.com alice.hoover@mail.com jteen@mail.com
```

But this seems like a very crude approach where grouping should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this in vim script is probably using 'g' substitute.

```
let list = []
call substitute(string, '<\zs[^>]\+\ze>', '\=add(list, submatch(0))', 'g')
echo join(list, ' ')
```

An more tedious alternative is to loop over matches using `matchstrpos()`.

There is also a too-clever solution with `split()`:

```
let list = string->split('<[^>]\+>\zs', 1)[0:-2]->map({_,x->x->matchstr('<\zs[^>]\+')})
echo list->join(' ')
```

The idea is to split *on* your pattern using `\zs` to keep the desired matches around, then grab the matches in each part.